# How To Revert Git Configurations

Tags: git

I used the command: **git config --global url."git://".insteadOf https://** , how do I revert to using https for https requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "revert" the change, but you can just remove the setting:

```
git config --global --unset url.git://.insteadOf
```

Or you can open your git configuration in an editor and remove it there:

```
git config --global --edit
```

And then remove the